# Windows Phone 8.1: отправка email сообщений

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, email

Как можно отправить email сообщение с телефона ко мне на почту? Например, я хочу отправлять себе эксепшены на почту, но чтобы пользователь об этом даже не знал.

Использовал такой код:

```
Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage mail = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();
mail.Subject = "This is Subject";
mail.Body = "This is body of demo mail";
mail.To.Add(new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailRecipient("erickvoodoo1993@gmail.com", "shaomeng"));
await Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(mail);
```

При подключении учетной записи google оно предлагает отправить через нее сообщение. Но пользователю будет выведена менюшка для заполнения данных для отправки. Мне нужно, чтобы было без этого и независимо от того, подключена какая-либо учетная запись какого-либо сервиса для отправки сообщений.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Официального" способа отправлять емейлы, не используя персональные аккаунты пользователя, в WP8 нельзя. Есть геморройный способ:

1. Зарезолвить mail-exchanger сервер для почтового ящика, куда вы хотите отправить сообщение.
2. Открыть сокет к этому серверу.
3. Слать нужные SMTP  команды для отправки сообщения. При этом поле ОТ можно заполнить произвольно.

В сети есть различные библиотеки для работы с SMTP.

Однако встает другой вопрос: если все, что вы хотите добиться, это слать возникшие в приложении ошибки, не проще ли будет заиспользовать многочисленные готовые решения? Я, например, пользуюсь Yandex.Metrica.

Comment: Довольно геморно на самом деле.
А метрика работает только с сайтами?

Comment: Нет, для приложений тоже есть:
https://tech.yandex.ru/metrica-mobile-sdk/doc/mobile-sdk-dg/concepts/about-docpage/